# Laravel Hide ID from url

Tags: php, laravel

I want to hide `id` from `URL`, I have database table that contains `store_id`, `store_name`, `store_city` and `store_zipcode` fields, now its working like this:

`http://example.com/store/1/Cafe-Crsip-Chicago-60640`

But I want it to change like this:

`http://example.com/store/Cafe-Crsip-Chicago-60640`

without showing `id` in `URL`.

**ROUTE:**

```
Route::get('store/{id}/{slug}',['as'=>'showProducts','uses'=>'FrontController@getProduct']);
```

**HREF:**

```
<a href="store/{{$store->store_id}}/{{str_replace(' ', '-', $store->store_name)}}-{{str_replace(' ', '-', $store->store_city)}}-{{$store->store_zipcode}}">
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
 public function getProduct(int $id, string $slug)
 {
  $products = Product::where(['store_id'=>$id])
    ->orderBy('category_id', 'asc')
    ->with('category','relatedproducts', 'relatedproducts.product')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('category_id');
 }
```

**Please note** that Im using str_replace to remove any spaces in url so if  I used store/{slug} the parameters from url will not be the same if I modified the url using str_replace

Comment: You might need to add another row to your table say 'slug' so you can query by that. Have you thought about this direction?

Comment: Yes its better to have a unique slug column in your products table so you can allocate a single product by its unique url

Comment: Use one of the many sluggable traits available - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-slugs-in-laravel-5?page=0

Comment: Change your where clause to search by slug and remove the id from the route and controller args. A trait package may help to get around all the points in one shot.

Comment: It is good idea to create new column `slug` in your database table and change your `URL` to use `slug` instead of `id` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is just added new column in the stores table which named slug
this slug will have the name of the store,city and zip-code (all these together cant be duplicated)

Cafe-Crsip-Chicago-60640
this can be add during adding new store with small function to combine the 3 fields together and save it in the field slug
in route added this

```
 Route::get('{slug}',['as'=>'showProducts','uses'=>'FrontController@getProduct']);
```

in controller

```
  public function getProduct(string $slug)
  {

 $storesid = Storeinfo::where(['store_slug'=> $slug])->get()->first();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new route:

```
Route::get('store/{slug}',['as'=>'showProducts','uses'=>'FrontController@getProduct']);
```

Change the Href to :

```
<a href="store/{{str_replace(' ', '_', $store->store_name)}}-{{str_replace(' ', '_', $store->store_city)}}-{{$store->store_zipcode}}">
```

Notice i changed the - to _ in the str_replace

Then change the controller to look for the store_name, store_city and store_zipcode instead of the store_id

Something in the lines of :

```
public function getProduct(string $slug)
{
    $slugs = explode("-", str_replace('_', ' ', $slug)); // replace the _ back to spaces and separate the 3 parts of the slug
    $products = Product::where([
            'store_name'=>$slugs[0], 'store_city'=>$slugs[1], 'store_zipcode'=>$slugs[2]
        ])
        ->orderBy('category_id', 'asc')
        ->with('category','relatedproducts', 'relatedproducts.product')
        ->get()->groupBy('category_id');}
```

Hope this helps!

Like @waterloomatt mentioned you could also do it by using the slug helper that laravel gives us but i don't know exactly how it would work.

Comment: A redirect on every link is probably not the best idea for performance and user experience. A simple slug would solve the issue.

Comment: @waterloomatt I read the link to the laracast you posted, i didn't know you could add the slug later in. It's a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: @BenoitRouleau your solution will not work because I want also to remove the spaces using str_replace and why to use to routes it will be the same, can you explain more how to modify the href?

Comment: @Glove if you want to change the href, you don't need the second route. I'll edit my answer with the code for the href

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide URL path parameters instead but redirecting. You can set your route parameter "id" optional

```
Route::get('store/{id?}/{slug}',['as'=>'showProducts','uses'=>'FrontController@getProduct']);
```

Then your query will not get any id parameter and 
You will get error like **"Laravel Type error: Too few arguments to function"**

It is better to use your slug as identification column to avoid using id.
Then your route will be

```
Route::get('store/{slug}',['as'=>'showProducts','uses'=>'FrontController@getProduct']);
```

and remove id parameter from controller then use slug for the query.

Comment: store/{slug} I know it will work but the problem I have to no use str_replace, how can I use str_replace to remove %20 in url?

Comment: you can use the function urldecode('your url');
you will find details here [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php]

Comment: what I did just added new column to database called store_slug and its working like this $storesid = Storeinfo::where(['store_slug'=> $slug])->get()->first();

$products = Product::where('store_id',$storesid->store_id)

Comment: @Glove, If this is a solution to the problem then please accept this answer

Comment: this is not the good solution, the solution is just to add the slug into database

Comment: @Glove, please comment here when you get the answer, It will be very helpful, thank you :)